# Need help on a sql query to get data from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a couple of tables that have data in them that I am looking to get information from.  Here is the rundown....In table 1 I have bunch of columns that I am pulling data from, one of the columns is a user ID (which is a number)that was the last userID to modify a record.  In  table 2 I want to pull in the name of that user based on the ID that is pulled from the other table (this table has both the userID and the username).

so my final query would have the columns in table 1 as well as the username from table 2 to show that was the user to last edit the record.  I assume this has to be done in a nested select statement but for the life of me I cannot come up with the correct syntax.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks
Jeff

Comment: There are tons of online resources for this. Here's one: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a very basic join that link both tables together.

```
Select t1.UserID, 
       t2.UserName
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN 
     table2 t2 ON t1.userid=t2.userid
```

Comment: Thanks Ala - that worked for one of the columns.  If I wanted to do 2 reference columns in the same command, how would I do that?  Example would be in table 1 there are 2 ID's (editedby and Createdby) that connect to the same ID in table 2.  I would like to get both of those column values.

Comment: Nevermind - I got it working by using 2 inner join statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t1.*, t2.{username} from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2 on t1.{userId}=t2.{userid};
```

change `{username}` with the actual column name of user
similarly `{userId}` with appropriate column name in tables.

Hope it helps you.
this is standard inner join query, to learn more consider reading: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/